# passport-discord react problem Access-Control-Allow-origin

Tags: reactjs, express, discord, oauth, passport.js

I am trying to build a Front end app with React that can facilitate a Discord login, and I want to save the cookie and some parameters from Discord in my PostgreSQL database.

The Front end is developed in standard React, running on localhost:3000 :

```js
    async function submitDiscord(event) {
      const result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/discord", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/JSON",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setId(data.id);
          setAutherized(data.autherized);
          setHidden(true);
        });
    }

    ...<some html code >

    <button className="Form-Container-Button" onClick={submitDiscord}>
      Login with Discord
    </button>;
```

Back end is implemented in Express on localhost:5000. Here are the crucial lines of code:

```js
    app.use(
      cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        credentials: true,
      })
    );
    
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    passport.use(
      new DiscordStrategy(
        {
          clientID: process.env.Discord_ClientID,
          clientSecrete: process.env.Discord_Secrete,
          callbackURL: process.env.Discord_Callback,
          scope: ["identify", "email"],
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          console.log(accessToken, refreshToken);
          console.log(proifle);
        }
      )
    );
    
    app.get("/auth/discord", passport.authenticate("discord"));
    
    app.get(
      "/auth/discord/callback",
      passport.authenticate("discord", {
        failureRedirect: "localhost:3000/login",
        successRedirect: "localhost:3000/home",
      })
    );
```

I've tried every origin I can imagine to put in that CORS middleware, but I always encounter the CORS error. I also understand that I could deactivate the CORS settings, but because I intend for this project to go live someday, I need to find a way to make this possible.

I know it's a CORS error because the server is requesting to Discord, but the first request comes from localhost:3000 to localhost:5000, which is also cross-origin. However, there must be a way to solve this, as other websites are using third-party logins and saving emails, for example.

Comment: "I know it's a CORS error because..." — do you get any messages from the browser that indicate it is a CORS error? What responses and errors do you get from the browser? By the way, I'm not sure this will all work as you intend. In the React app you `await` the result from the `/auth/discord` request, but that endpoint starts an authentication flow with Discord, which will trigger some redirects for the user. Your app will not get a response from this request directly.

Comment: The error is as mentioned: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin." I came to the conclusion that it's probably better to handle the control with window.open and request the data from the server separately. But if you have any idee how you would do this feel free